# Controller life-cycle ASP.NET Core WebApi

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using asp.net core to develop a WebApi.

What is the life-cycle of controller in ASP.NET Core? Does it depends on the web server?

Answer (score 2):

Usually an instance of a controller is created per request and if you use dependency injection, all associated services are created for that request.